# Django adding global variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My problem, i want using query and adding variable to global and use this variable to anywhere django template same `request`.

Any suggestions or advice on how to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: An approach is to use `context_processors`

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: @Selcuk I think sessions can not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `context_processors`.

First, add your own `context_processors.py` in your app (like `common` app or something.)

```
def test_processors(requests):
    return {
        'my_test_context': 'test',
    }
```

Second, add it to `TEMPLATES.OPTIONS.context_processors' in`settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            str(ROOT_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # you can add here
                'myapp.context_processors.test_processor',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then you can use `'my_test_context'` in any templates.

Comment: @HpLam glad for helping!